# Kronecker Multiplication only with specific axis

Tags: python, numpy

how can I simplify and extend the following code for arbitrary shapes of A?

```
import numpy as np
A  = np.random.random([10,12,13,5,5])
B  = np.zeros([10,12,13,10,10])
s2 = np.array([[0,1],[-1,0]])

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(12):
        for k in range(13):
            B[i,j,k,:,:] = np.kron(A[i,j,k,:,:],s2)
```

I know it would be possible with np.einsum, but also there I would have to explicitly give the shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That output shape has to be computed for the last two axes -

```
out_shp = A.shape[:-2] + tuple(A.shape[-2:]*np.array(s2.shape))
```

Then `einsum` or explicit extension of dims could be used -

```
B_out = (A[...,:,None,:,None]*s2[:,None]).reshape(out_shp)

B_out = np.einsum('ijklm,no->ijklnmo',A,s2).reshape(out_shp)
```

That `einsum` one could be generalized more for generic dims with ellipsis `...` -

```
np.einsum('...lm,no->...lnmo',A,s2).reshape(out_shp)
```

**Extend to generic dims**

We can generalize to generic dims that would accept the axes along which the kronecker multiplications are to be performed with some *reshaping work* -

```
def kron_along_axes(a, b, axis):
    # Extend a to the extent of the broadcasted o/p shape
    ae = a.reshape(np.insert(a.shape,np.array(axis)+1,1))

    # Extend b to the extent of the broadcasted o/p shape
    d = np.ones(a.ndim,dtype=int)
    np.put(d,axis,b.shape)
    be = b.reshape(np.insert(d,np.array(axis),1))

    # Get o/p and reshape back to a's dims
    out = ae*be

    out_shp = np.array(a.shape)
    out_shp[list(axis)] *= b.shape
    return out.reshape(out_shp)
```

Thus, to solve our case, it would be -

```
B = kron_along_axes(A, s2, axis=(3,4))
```

**With `numpy.kron`**

If you are looking for elegance and okay with something slower, we can use the built-in `np.kron` too with some axes-permutations -

```
def kron_along_axes(a, b, axis):
    new_order = list(np.setdiff1d(range(a.ndim),axis)) + list(axis)
    return np.kron(a.transpose(new_order),b).transpose(new_order)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
flattened_A = A.reshape([-1, A.shape[-2], A.shape[-1]])
flattened_kron_product = np.kron(flattened_A, s2)
dims = list(A.shape[:-2]) + [flattened_kron_product.shape[-2], flattened_kron_product.shape[-1]]
result = flattened_kron_product.reshape(dims)
```

Subtracting `result` from `B` results in a zero filled. matrix.